# SignalR can´t reconnect after the application being a long time idle

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

My application is using WebSocket protocol and all the connection and communication proccess is working well. However, after a long time with the user away, the ws connection is broken, occurs a new call to `/signalr/negotiate?` but there is none call to `ws://localhost/signalr/connect`. Inspecting the response from `negotiate`, it´s all ok.

Comment: So you're handling the disconnected event and re-starting the connection is what I'm understanding.  Could you post some of your code and the response to the second negotiate.

Comment: Turn logging on, $.connection.hub.logging = true and see what the js console says.

Comment: The applications was running with an old client script version. I´ve updated it with version 1.1.2 and it´s all fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The applications was running with an old client script version. I´ve updated it with version 1.1.2 and it´s all fine now.